# Javascript RegExp ignores Metacharacters

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying hours to figure this out without any luck. Would be grateful if someone could point me to the right direction.

The problem is that the RegExp Object is totally ignoring the **\b** and **\s** Metacharacters.

```
var orOperator = 'or';
var term = 'ipsum';
var str = 'lorem or ipsum or ipsumal';
var regex = new RegExp('(\\s)\\b' + orOperator + '\\s' + term + '\\b', 'gi');
console.log(regex);

str = str.replace(regex, '');
```

While the resulting regex should be

```
/(\s)\bor\sipsum\b/gi
```

I keep getting this one instead (with Metacharacters stripped) and I don't know why

```
/(s)orsipsum/gi
```

Comment: what's the running environment of your script? I tried on Chrome, Safari and Firefox, all 3 gives me the result you expect

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://eval.in/606020 . How do you display the pattern?

Comment: @Yizheng Shen I've tried running the script in all browsers, still not getting the expected result.

Comment: @anubhava "_While the resulting regex should be_ `/(\s)\bor\s\bipsum\b/gi`" and not `/\sor\sipsum/gi`

Comment: Using `\b` one cannot search for partial words. It should be `/\sor\sipsum/`

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte I log it to the console, same as you did. I can't replicate it also outside my environment. I wonder what would make the RegExp behave this way.

Comment: I think my following words may not help but, as I remember in C++, two slash will squeeze to one slash and you need FOUR single slash to really get ONE slash for escaping

Comment: It isn't a regex problem, but a simple string problem. You wonder that you obtain a curious result when you "strip metacharacters" and when you display the string, but you must understand that `'\\'` doesn't represent two backslashes but a single backslash. `'\b'` will disappear because it represents the backspace character, and since `'\s'` doesn't represent anything, the backslash is stripped (ignored). You must make the difference between what contains a string and how to represent (to write) it.

Comment: @Yizheng Shen That worked! Four slashes did the trick. Don't really understand why though. :)

Comment: @YKal congrats! OS problem maybe? Anyway, problem solved, cheers! ✨

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `String.raw` tag function ([more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)) — it'll ignore (not process) any escape sequences *aka* metacharacters and allow substitutions:

```js
var orOperator = 'or';
var term = 'ipsum';
var str = 'lorem or ipsum or ipsumal';
var regexStr = String.raw`(\s)\b${orOperator}\s${term}\b`;
var regexFlags = 'gi';
var regex = new RegExp(regexStr, regexFlags);
console.log(regex);

str = str.replace(regex, '');
```

and result is

```js
/(\s)\bor\sipsum\b/gi
'lorem or ipsumal'
```

Answer (score 1):

As @YizhengShen and @CasimiretHippolyte suggested in the comments, 4 backslashes for each Metacharacter did the trick.

```js
var regex = new RegExp('(\\\\s)\\\\b' + orOperator + '\\\\s' + term + '\\\\b', 'gi');
```